# I want to pay one invoice through Quickbook payment gateway using cradit card

Tags: quickbooks-online

I have made an application in .net MVC and try to make  a payment using quickbook payment gateway.
But I cannot find the way how to make a payment for any invoice using credit card. Could you please provide me any documentation link for it.Could you please tel me the way to do so. Also how can I do so using .net application.

Answer (score 0):

A really quick Google search yields this documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/charges#create-a-charge

And even .NET sample code:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/develop/using-an-sdk-to-integrate-with-the-payments-api#net